# Remove specific tag with its contents using sed

Tags: html, sed

I would like to remove following tag from HTML including its constantly varying contents:

```
<span class="the_class_name">li4tuq734g23r74r7Whatever</span>
```

A following BASH script

```
.... | sed -e :a -re 's/<span class="the_class_name"/>.*</span>//g' > "$NewFile"
```

ends with error

> sed: -e expression #2, char XX: unknown option to `s'

I tried to escape quotes, slashes and "less than" symbols in various combinations and still get this error.

Comment: Ok, first problem gone. Time to work on the regex :-) You see the `/` in the first `span` tag in your regex? That doesn't seem to match your input. Perhaps `sed -E 's,<span class="the_class_name">[^<]*</span>,,g'` would be better

Comment: `sed '\#<span class="the_class_name">[^<]*</span>#d'`

Comment: @HatLess That'd delete the whole line if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Does `the_class_name` occur only once in the XML file?

Comment: @Cyrus: Multiple times. All I want to do is to download a web page with wget, remove all the information that changes each time and if the new file differs from the previous one - send a message over Jabber.

Comment: I suggest to add your XML file to your question (no comment) with unimportant parts removed. It is important that the file is still a valid XML file.

Comment: It's HTML. Doesn't have to be a valid XML. And it's too long for being posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a different [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) separator than `/` when `/` is contained within the thing you want to match on. Also, prefer `-E` instead of `-r` for extended regex to be Posix compatible. Also note that you have a `/` in your first `span` in your regex that doesn't belong there.
Also, `.*` will make it overly greedy and eat up any `</span>` that follows the first `</span>` on the line. It's better to match on `[^<]*`. That is, any character that is *not* `<`.

```
sed -E 's,<span class="the_class_name">[^<]*</span>,,g'
```

A better option is of course to use a HTML parser for this.

Comment: Ted, you seem to have a lot of experience with processing HTML on the command line. What command line HTML parser would you suggest?

Comment: @Paul I _had_ xp doing that some 20 years ago :-) I don't remember much. Cyrus suggested a few above. I recognize `xmllint` so that's been around for a long time.